# Syntax Error - missing operator, semicolon, or '}' near 'drawFrieze'

Tags: syntax-error, processing, custom-function

I am a beginner programmer taking a programming class using Processing 4. I have a project that is meant to use loops and custom functions to create a complex pattern. I have code that works without functions,  but when I tried to rewrite it with functions I keep running into the error: "Syntax error - missing operator, semicolon, or '}' near 'drawFrieze'. The interesting thing is, when I take out the drawFrieze function, the error moves to the next function.

I've double checked the formatting of the function, and it has the proper  number of curly  brackets and semicolons. I've tried moving the functions before void draw() and  even putting it  on  a separate tab,  but the error still shows up. I don't  know what I did wrong and I would appreciate input from more experienced people.

```java
/*
Kathrine Lee
ITGM 220
Complex Pattern
7/12/2023
*/

void setup () {
size(1000,800);
background(black);
}

//color palette
color linen = color(#fef5ec);
color lightBlue = color(#95d2da);
color blue = color(#158da2);
color gold = color(#cc9214);
color tangerine = color(#ea851f);
color redOrange = color(#da481d);
color springGreen = color(#246f49);
color darkGreen = color(#173b28);
color black = color(#090607);

void drawCircles(float circlesX,float circlesY) {
 noStroke();
 fill(redOrange);
 rect(0,200,1000,400);
 noFill();
 { for(int x=0; x<1200; x=x+100){
  for(int y=0; y<500; y=y+100){
    stroke(gold);
    strokeWeight(10);
    circle(x,y+200,100);
  }
 }
}

{ for(int x=0; x<1200; x=x+100){
  for(int y=0; y<500; y=y+100){
    stroke(tangerine);
    strokeWeight(10);
    circle(x+50,y+250,100);
  }
 }
}

void drawFrieze(float friezeX, float friezeY) {
  noStroke();
  fill(black);
  rect(0,0,1000,200);
  rect(0,600,1000,200);
  noStroke();
  fill(linen);
  rect(0,50,1000,125);
  noStroke();
  fill(linen);
  rect(0,650,1000,725);
  stroke(blue);
  strokeWeight(10);
  noFill();
  line(0,0,1000,0);
  stroke(redOrange);
  line(0,10,1000,10);
  stroke(darkGreen);
  line(0,20,1000,20);
  line(0,50,1000,50);
  line(0,170,1000,170);
  line(0,200,1000,200);
   {for(int x=0; x<width; x=x+120){
     noStroke();
     fill(gold);
     rect(x,25,10,25);
     rect(x+40,25,10,25);
     rect(x+80,25,10,25);
     fill(blue);
     rect(x+10,25,30,25);
     fill(redOrange);
     rect(x+50,25,30,25);
     fill(springGreen);    
     rect(x+90,25,30,25);
     noFill();
     stroke(darkGreen);
     strokeWeight(5);
     line(x,25,x,50);
     line(x+10,25,x+10,50);
     line(x+40,25,x+40,50);
     line(x+50,25,x+50,50);
     line(x+80,25,x+80,50);
     line(x+90,25,x+90,50);
     noStroke();
     fill(gold);
     rect(x,175,10,25);
     rect(x+40,175,10,25);
     rect(x+80,175,10,25);
     fill(blue);
     rect(x+10,175,30,25);
     fill(redOrange);
     rect(x+50,175,30,25);
     fill(springGreen);    
     rect(x+90,175,30,25);
     noFill();
     stroke(darkGreen);
     strokeWeight(5);
     line(x,175,x,200);
     line(x+10,175,x+10,200);
     line(x+40,175,x+40,200);
     line(x+50,175,x+50,200);
     line(x+80,175,x+80,200);
     line(x+90,175,x+90,200);
    }
  }
}

void drawLotus(float lotusX, float lotusY) {
{for(int x=0; x<900; x=x+85){
  stroke(darkGreen);
  strokeWeight(3);
  fill(lightBlue);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+45,70);
    bezierVertex(x+50,77,x+55,80,x+63,90);
    bezierVertex(x+70,100,x+68,110,x+66,110);
    vertex(x+50,120);
    vertex(x+30,120);
    vertex(x+22,110);
    bezierVertex(x+20,100,x+20,97,x+28,90);
    bezierVertex(x+35,82,x+38,77,x+45,70);
  endShape();
  fill(springGreen);
  rect(x+40,120,10,20);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+45,105);
    bezierVertex(x+48,108,x+52,111,x+51,117);
    bezierVertex(x+54,112,x+58,108,x+66,110);
    bezierVertex(x+65,113,x+62,119,x+56,121);
    bezierVertex(x+53,122,x+51,123,x+47,124);
    bezierVertex(x+43,125,x+42,124,x+40,125);
    bezierVertex(x+36,124,x+33,124,x+28,119);
    bezierVertex(x+23,114,x+23,112,x+22,108);
    bezierVertex(x+27,110,x+33,113,x+37,117);
    bezierVertex(x+38,112,x+38,107,x+45,105);
  endShape();
  noStroke();
  fill(darkGreen);
  circle(x+45,150,30);
  fill(springGreen);
  circle(x+45,150,20);
  fill(gold);
  circle(x+45,150,10);
  stroke(darkGreen);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+85,115);
    vertex(x+75,73);
    vertex(x+78,68);
    bezierVertex(x+80,65,x+84,58,x+87,58);
    bezierVertex(x+90,58,x+94,67,x+95,70);
    vertex(x+97,73);
    vertex(x+90,115);
    vertex(x+85,115);
  endShape();
  fill(blue);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+85,110);
    bezierVertex(x+86,96,x+81,81,x+78,66);
    bezierVertex(x+63,51,x+58,60,x+54,66);
    bezierVertex(x+74,71,x+75,96,x+75,113);
    bezierVertex(x+78,112,x+81,112,x+85,110);
  endShape();
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+90,110);
    bezierVertex(x+90,96,x+91,72,x+95,69);
    bezierVertex(x+100,63,x+105,51,x+120,66);
    bezierVertex(x+104,73,x+99,75,x+97,114);
    bezierVertex(x+94,113,x+92,112,x+90,110);
  endShape();
  fill(springGreen);
  rect(x+84,124,6,40);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+75,115);
    vertex(x+87,110);
    vertex(x+98,115);
    bezierVertex(x+97,117,x+100,125,x+87,128);
    bezierVertex(x+82,127,x+75,124,x+75,115);
  endShape();
  }
 }
}

void drawEyes(float eyesX, float eyesY) {
{for(int x=0;x<width;x=x+200){
  stroke(black);
  strokeWeight(10);
  fill(linen);
  beginShape();
    vertex(x+86,260);
    bezierVertex(x+146,325,x+148,485,x+86,550);
    bezierVertex(x+26,485,x+20,325,x+86,260);
  endShape();
  noStroke();
  fill(darkGreen);
  if (x>200) {
    fill(springGreen);
  }
  if (x>600) {
    fill(blue);
  }
  circle(x+86,410,90);
  fill(springGreen);
  if (x>200) {
    fill(blue);
  }
  if (x>600) {
    fill(lightBlue);
  }
  circle(x+86,410,60);
  fill(blue);
  if (x>100) {
    fill(lightBlue);
  }
  if (x>200) {
    fill(darkGreen);
  }
  if (x>400) {
    fill(lightBlue);
  }
  if (x>600) {
    fill(blue);
  }
  circle(x+86,410,40);
  fill(black);
  circle(x+86,410,20);
  }
 }
}

void draw () {
  drawCircles(0,0);
  drawFrieze(0,0);
  drawFrieze(0,600);
  drawLotus(0,0);
  drawLotus(0,600);
  drawEyes(0,0);
}
```

Comment: In addition to the comments in the answer given, you're not using the function parameters; either use them or delete them. I don't think you need to set the background color initially because it appears to add nothing. The color palette doesn't appear to be working; everything is in black and white on my system.

Comment: Look up the reference for fill: https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html. Something like fill(#D39C24) and stroke(#EA4928) works on my system.

Comment: If you want to use your color palette, then try something like this: color blue = color(64, 124, 188); using RGB values.

Comment: Sidenote: always use the Processing IDE's auto-formatter so that when you do have problems like this, you can paste code that everyone can easily read. As for the problem, the effect you're seeing (deleting a function and seeing the error move) tells you that the error happens _before_ the location that the error is flagging. E.g. you forgot to close one function before starting the next, or forgetting to add a semi-colon before moving on to a next line of code. The parser won't see things being wrong until it runs into unexpected input which is always _after_ where you forgot something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a "}" to close out drawCircles.  Also note you do not need to have your "for loops" surrounded by braces.  It is making it harder to spot the issue with the code.

```
void drawCircles(float circlesX,float circlesY) {
 noStroke();
 fill(redOrange);
 rect(0,200,1000,400);
 noFill();
 for(int x=0; x<1200; x=x+100){
  for(int y=0; y<500; y=y+100){
    stroke(gold);
    strokeWeight(10);
    circle(x,y+200,100);
  }
 }

 for(int x=0; x<1200; x=x+100){
  for(int y=0; y<500; y=y+100){
    stroke(tangerine);
    strokeWeight(10);
    circle(x+50,y+250,100);
  }
 }
} // end drawCircles
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @KathrineLee if the answer was helpful consider [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer and if it was the solution to your problem please mark it as such with the green check mark. This will make it easier for anyone to easily spot the solution to your issue in case they run into the same issue themselves.